# How to initialize Ruby Datamapper object from JSON?

Tags: ruby, json, datamapper

I'm using Ruby with Sinatra and DataMapper.  It is simple enough to create a "get" webservice that delivers a data set to a UI with something like `Item.all().to_json`
However, the intent is for the UI to use the data set for crud work and return a single JSON object for add or update.  I haven't found an equivalent "from_json" DataMapper function to initialize an Item object.

As a work-around, I'm using JSON.parse, like this:

`item_data = JSON.parse(request.body.read, :quirks_mode => true)`

This works, but then I have to create a new DataMapper object, i.e. `item = Item.new`, 
and copy all the elements from item_data to item, but I'd like to think there's a simpler way.

Any and all suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have:

```
class Item
   property :body, String
end
```

So you might want to do this:

```
class Item
   property :body, Json
end
```

The Json style property, works just like String, the only difference is that on load/store the data will go through the JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!

You can create a helper like this:

```
helpers do
  def json_params
    begin
      JSON.parse(request.body.read)
    rescue
      halt 400, { message:'Invalid JSON' }.to_json
    end
  end
end
```

And create your Datamapper object:

```
@object = Object.new(json_params)
@object.save
```